# Script file to enable sysadmin role in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hello I am trying to find a script or batch file to enable sysadmin account under server roles for the NT Authority\system in SQL Server 2012.

I have installed SQL Server in mixed mode but the `sa` role is disabled by default.

The reason I am looking for a script is because I want to ad the script to my MSI build to automatically enable the sa account so my PM's don't have to.

I have minimal knowledge on scripting so detailed answers would help a lot.

'sysadmin' is a role, 'sa' is the 'system administrator's login.

If you installed just using Windows Authentication (default mode), the 'sa' account is already there, but will be disabled by default. Look under YourServerName -> Security -> Logins in Management Studio, and you should see 'sa' with a down-arrow in the icon (symbolises a disabled user)

Comment: Would you check this link, it may helps you. It also have a script that is achieving that (if I fully understood your requirements) http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/addselftosqlsysadmin/

Comment: I don't want to add me to the sysadmin role, I want to have the sysadmin account added the NT Authority\system login as a role. Only public is checked by default in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I want to have the sysadmin account added as a role to the NT authority\system login with a script.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so from this comment:

"I want to have the sysadmin account added as a role to the NT authority\system login with a script."

I understand your question as you don't want to enable the SA login, you just want to add the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM login to the sysadmin server role?

If this is what you want to do then you simply have to run the following

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
```

This will give the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account sysadmin rights to the server, we have to do the same thing in order for our CommVault backup software to work.

Comment: This will give the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account sysadmin rights to the serverYes that is exactly

Comment: What I want to do. Where are these commands run? Can they be put in a script, or run in the SQLCMD utility?

Comment: I do not want my project Managers getting into SQL Server Management Studio if I can help it.

Comment: Yes, you can just create a T-SQL Script and run this either yourself in SQL Management studio, or via SQLCMD or any other way you like really.

Comment: Thank you so far this is what I have in my .bat file echo off, SQLCMD -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P xxxxxxxx this connects me to the data base but the ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin} does not start automatically I get a prompt that looks like this 1> and if I enter the commands after each number it adds the sa login, but I want this to run automaticly.

Comment: You need to specify the query in the command to make it run automatically "SQLCMD -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P xxxxxxxx -Q "ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]" should do it, have a look at the SQLcmd docs here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx